# Any known glitches for Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization 5 when you make a research agreement with an AI then go to war with that player, you get the free tech instantly.

Are there any other abuses like this?

Comment: Rgd. res.agreement: This [ http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7890/3773 ] seems to say otherwise!

Comment: @Martin and Eric: that glitch is a bug that was fixed in the October 2010 patch.

Comment: Trade agreements are broken upon war, so you can request all the gold in an empire's treasury, in return for GPT and goods. Declare war, and your GPT and goods will be returned, but you keep the gold. Also, I've seen an instance where a city-state started gaining 10-15 influence a turn to no end, but I haven't been able to replicate that feat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Angkor Wat only affects the city it's built in, not every city like the description says. It went from being an incredible wonder to worthless in about 10 minutes it took me to figure that out.